# JS way to enable/disable JQ-Chosen select

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel

So I have this dilemma of disabling the select statement with `ui-jq="chosen"` as its front-end design. Although this is part of a Laravel project, hope someone can help me fix this problem under JS alone.

Using a checkbox to disable/enable the select statement that is under `chosen`, the `disabled` attribute doesn't work with it.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkerBox" id="checker" @if ($leave->onProject) checked @endif onclick="selectHider()">

<select name="leave_id" ui-jq="chosen" class="w-full" id="selection"> //options snipped <select>
```

then for the JS script below

```
function selectHider() {
      var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkerBox");

      if (checkBox.checked == true){
        document.getElementById("selection").disabled = false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("selection").disabled = true;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function selectHider() {
      var checkBox = document.getElementById("checkerBox");
      //You can set disable default here, depend on your logic
      document.getElementById("selection").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

      if (checkBox.checked == true){
        document.getElementById("selection").removeAttribute("disabled");
      } 
}
```

Comment: didn't work. tried your way as well as tested by adding the setAttribute statement as an else rather than set by default